# Hypothetically, according to the Standard Model, if the universe were not expanding, could we not cut out the Big Bang and inflation?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang, cosmological-inflation, redshift

Hypothetically, according to the Standard Model, if the universe were not expanding, could we not cut out the Big Bang and inflation and begin the universe in an expanded state and still get the same universe? I'm not suggesting that the universe was eternal or that things happened without a chain of causation. I just want to know what difference it would make if we removed the Big Bang and inflation from our history's narrative and began post inflation. If the universe began already spread out in the same distribution and radiation, it should create the same ratio of elements and same distribution of galaxies, etc. And popping into existence already expanded is just as explained as the Big Bang popping into existence, so, expansion aside, why can't this work?

Comment: The universe could also have begun yesterday, and all your memories would just be the result of accidental initial conditions resulting in the matter distribution which comprises your neurons in this very specific way. If you can accept the initial conditions of the universe without inflation, why not also accept this explanation :)

Comment: This set of exchanges reveals the total arbitrariness of the choice of presumed initial conditions that supposedly preceded our presently understood (!?) astronomically observed universe, an arbitrariness risibly supported by democratic appeal to the supposed fancied predilections of some undefined majority. Not to mention the suppositious predilection for a starting point, an origin, a beginning, examination of which necessarily involves us in the psychological foibles of the proponents of such dicta.

Answer (score 1):

> If the universe began already spread out in the same distribution and radiation, it should create the same ratio of elements and same distribution of galaxies, etc.

Well, if we hypothesize that the universe began only after inflation with the post-inflation conditions as the initial conditions then yes, by definition it would have the same distribution of radiation and galaxies and ratio of elements. But then the question would be why did it suddenly pop into existence like this? "It just did" is not a very satisfying answer.

> And popping into existence already expanded is just as explained as the Big Bang popping into existence

No, not nearly. The Big Bang was a rather simple and well defined initial condition, after which the quantum fluctuations during inflation naturally led to conditions that produced the current observed large-scale structure of the universe. As an initial condition starting post-inflation would be rather bizarrely unlikely out of all of the possible initial conditions. The standard big bang model has only 6 free parameters. A model starting post-inflation would have a huge number of free parameters describing the stress energy content of the entire initial universe at a quantum level. This would take a lot more than 6 parameters.

Also, if you say that the universe began post-inflation, what actual evidence can you point to for a specific time post-inflation? Did it start a second later? If not, why not? Why not a bit earlier or a bit later than whatever guess you make? And how do you make a precise statement about the end of inflation? A singularity is a good reason to start or stop but another boundary just doesn't have any observational support. It is thus a poorly-defined initial condition.

Comment: Who said the universe was young or began recently? You do realize that "the inflationary epoch lasted from 10−36 seconds after the conjectured Big Bang singularity to some time between 10−33 and 10−32 seconds after the singularity," right? Cutting out that little bit of time doesn't change the age of the universe very much. I don't see how we can relate our current conditions to the Big Bang and inflation. If the initial condition is that the universe began post inflation, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @CodyLivengood I have a sense that no answer will satisfy you but your own (this is your second time asking the same thing), however the *logic* is that the expansion did not spontaneously start at some arbitrary point (as you want it to) but carried back to a starting state that was simplest (from a physics point of view).  It's not a brief period of time in terms of all that happened, it's just brief in human terms.  Who say it happened this way ?  The vast majority of physicists who have studied this in great detail as a career.

Comment: So, basically, no one can come up with a reason (besides expansion) why we need the Big Bang and inflation and couldn't just begin post inflation? I assumed that was the case. Just wanted confirmation.

Comment: Ah, I did misunderstand your proposal. Indeed, I thought you were talking about recently. I have updated my answer. No, it is not correct that nobody can come up with a reason, my answer is not confirmation of that. I just misunderstood the question and have now corrected the answer

Comment: In this scenario, it began already expanded and no Big Bang or inflation or expansion ever took place. That is the initial starting condition, and so it is simple and well-defined. Whether or not that could actually be proven isn't relevant to a hypothetical question, just that IF it was, then that would destroy the theories of the Big Bang and inflation. I was just making sure other parameters weren't connected to the Big Bang and inflation that couldn't exist in the hypothetical scenario. I figured there wasn't any but just wanted confirmation.

Comment: No, such an initial starting condition is neither simple nor well-defined. It would actually not destroy the big bang theory in any case because, by design, it does not provide any testable difference from the big bang theory. In other words, from a scientific standpoint it introduces a lot of model variability without adding any predictive power. Thus it is a weaker theory